# Does the sequence $x_n = x_n(t) = e^{-nt}$ converge in space $M[0,2]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

$M[0,2] = \{x_n=x_n(t): sup|x_n(t)| < \infty , 0\leq t\leq2 \}$

The norm is $||x_n|| = sup |x_n(t)|, 0\leq t \leq 2$

I must investigate the size $sup |x_n(t)-f(t)| = sup |e^{-nt}-f(t)|, 0\leq t \leq 2$. How to find a function $f(t)$?

I think that $x_n$ not converge in $M[0,2]$.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that convergence with respect to the supremum norm clearly implies point wise converges. Thus, if the $x_n$'s converge in $M[0,2]$ then they converge to the point wise limit which is precisely
$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
1 &t=0\\
0 & 0<t\leq 2
\end{cases}
$$
Now, we check if $x_n$ also converges to $f$ with respect to the supremum norm. First note that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
x_n-f(t) = \begin{cases}
0 &t=0\\
e^{-nt} & 0<t\leq 2
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lVert x_n -f\rVert = \sup_{0\leq t\leq 2} \lvert x_n(t) - f(t) \rvert
=\sup_{0< t\leq 2} e^{-nt} = 1
$$
Hence, the $x_n$'s do not converge since they do not tend to their point wise limit.

Comment: Thank You :) @MathUser_NotPrime

Comment: One question about $\sup e^{-nt}$, if $0<t<=2$. How to explain this?

Comment: On the interval $(0, 2]$ the function is monotone decreasing (you can show this in many ways, e.g. the derivative is negative). Thus, $\sup_{0< t\leq 2} e^{-nt} = \lim_{t\to 0} e^{-nt}$